# Mongoose and Bluebird saveAsync not actually saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, bluebird

I am attempting to update an existing record in Mongo DB and although the "save" completes successfully, The record in the DB is not actually updated. Here's a before an after of the data:

Before:

```
{
    _id: '56be4ba9938e836b6f47e84a',
    type: 'ec-input',
    key: 'ec-input_2',
    templateOptions: {
        placeholder: 'My Placeholder...',
        subtext: 'My Subtest',
        label: 'My Label'
    },
    order: 1,
    form: '56bd3e76413de7c862979b8c',
    __v: 0
}
```

After:

```
{
    _id: '56be4ba9938e836b6f47e84a',
    type: 'ec-input',
    key: 'ec-input_2',
    templateOptions: {
        placeholder: 'I am different now!!',
        subtext: 'Me too..',
        label: 'My Label'
    },
    order: 1,
    form: '56bd3e76413de7c862979b8c',
    __v: 0
}
```

The `templateOptions` field is configured as type `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed` on the mongoose model. Here's how i'm trying to save the update:

```
export function update(req, res) {
  if (req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
  }

  Field.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
    .then(entity => {
      var updated = _.merge(entity, req.body);
      updated.saveAsync()
        .spread(updated => {
          if (entity) {
            res.status(200).json(entity);
          }
        });
    });
}
```

I set a breakpoint before `updated.saveAsync` is called and `updated` correctly has the modified data. I also set a breakpoint in the `spread` callback, and `updated` still has the modified data. After `updated.saveAsync` is complete, I check mongo directly, and the record was not updated.

Any ideas about what I can do to make this work would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. `entity` here is a "mongoose document" and not just a plain object. If you want to use things like `_.merge()` you need to first convert to a plain object via `.toObject()` and then re-cast as a mongoose document with `new Field()` before you call `.save()`. But you should not be doing that anyway, and should really be using the MongoDB [atomic update operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) instead, along with [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: Note that `_.extend()` applies differently and would work without the other manipulation here due to its internal workings.

Comment: Thank you. I got the `_.merge()` technique from the yeoman generator I use. I was able to find an open issue in their repo about this: https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/310

Comment: I would then strongly suggest choosing a different generator or at the very least making a point of overwriting the boilerplate code generated since the techinique is very wrong and a bad practice. I would also suggest the [CRUD Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/crud/) so you become familiar with how you should be applying queries and updates. Using rather `.findByIdAndUpdate()`, you can apply changes in a single trip to the database rather than "two", as well as avoid possible overwrites of data you don't really need/want to change.